# R flextables changing table caption style

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, flextable

I am having trouble changing the style of my table caption using flexible package together with a plain word document.

I just saved an empty word document as `ref.docx` and created a new rmarkdown document with the following content:

````
---
title: "caption test"
author: 
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d/%m/%Y')`"
geometry: "left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=3.11cm,bottom=2.5cm"
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: ref.docx

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, 
                      tab.cap.style = 'AnnotationTok',
                      tab.cap.pre = 'Tab...')
library(flextable)
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)


```

Somehow I want to get a table with a caption on top of it.




```{r,echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE,ft.align="left"}
ft <- flextable(head(mtcars))
ft <- autofit(ft)
ft <- set_caption(ft, 'test test 1 2 3',
                  style = 'AnnotationTok')
ft
```
````

Whatever I try, the style of the caption stays `normal`.

I tried adding it to `opts_chunk` to have it global, as well as trying within the `set_caption` function. Somehow it show no effect.

Setting `tab.cap.pre` to a different value then default is working as expected.

How do I change the style of the caption. How do I figure out the correct name? At the moment, I select my preferred style -> click edit -> and then I copy and paste this name.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to comment from @David, I was able to check which styles are in my reference document:

```
x <- read_docx('ref.docx')
officer::styles_info(x)
```

I can now set the style in the `set_caption` function, but the global setting with `tab.cap.style` is not working. Am I doing something wrong here?

For now my problem is mostly solved. Just wonder what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I assume style `AnnotationTok` does not exists in the docx template, pandoc will then associate 'Normal' the default one to your caption. See https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/office-documents-generation.html#word-document-styles. You can use function `officer:: styles_info()` to get the existing style names.

Comment: Hi David, I used the standard document and there are actually two with the same name... I tried `Headline 1` for example, no effect. The styles are in my document... Will check with the function u suggested!

Comment: Hi @DavidGohel that seems to be the issue for my example. Now I figured out, I can select a specific style in `set_caption`. But `tab.cap.style` in the `opts_chunk` function does not work. For now it is not to problematic, but I am wondering if I doing it wrong...

Comment: tab.cap.style should work unless set_caption(style='something') is used, in that cas, we use 'something'.

Comment: @DavidGohel does not work for me... The `tab.cap.style` has no function in my case... It stays `Table Caption`. flextables 0.7.3

Comment: OK thanks for letting me know. I am working on captions (and quarto), will add tests about them and make sure it's consistent.